# Xcode 12 Error: Multiple commands produce Charts.framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
Showing Recent Messages
Multiple commands produce '/Users/felicity/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZotCovidCare-fhtbaocguqoohrcfhiuujnxoblim/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ZotCovidCare.app/Frameworks/Charts.framework':
1) Target 'ZotCovidCare' (project 'ZotCovidCare') has copy command from '/Users/felicity/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZotCovidCare-fhtbaocguqoohrcfhiuujnxoblim/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Charts.framework' to '/Users/felicity/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZotCovidCare-fhtbaocguqoohrcfhiuujnxoblim/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ZotCovidCare.app/Frameworks/Charts.framework'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'ZotCovidCare' (project 'ZotCovidCare'): script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
```

I downloaded cocoapods and installed the Charts for my project. However, I can't build my project according to the error above. Please help me and thanks in advance!
P.s. I'm not sure if it's because of my cocoapods version. It's not the latest because I can't download that. I would really appreciate it if fix the error without updating cocoapods' version.

Comment: After I update cocoapods to 1.10, the problem still not fixed...

Answer (score 0):

I think I figure it out, simply delete the /Users/felicity/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZotCovidCare-fhtbaocguqoohrcfhiuujnxoblim/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Charts.framework and it built successfully!